# Images are small in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm trying to show a list of books in GridView and images are smaller than expected. I searched for this problem and found some answers on stackoverflow which tell to use 
`imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` in my adapter, but it didn't help me no matter how I tried.

[here's my problem screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTtjY.png)

Here's my **BookAdapter.java**
`

```
package com.example.android.slavabooks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
    public BookAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridView = convertView;
        if (gridView == null) {
            gridView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_book, parent, false);
        }


        Book currentBook = getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
        TextView author = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.author_text_view);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.book_image);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(currentBook.getBookImage());

        title.setText(currentBook.getTitle());
        author.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

        return gridView;
    }

}`
```

Here's my **activity_search_results.xml** with a **GridView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchResults">
    <GridView
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**one_book.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="12sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_image"
        android:src="@drawable/book"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/book_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_text_view"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Author"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `scaleType` in imageview?

Comment: **GridView:** 10dp padding, 10dp spacing, **RelativeLayout:** 12sp padding, 5dp margin. --> 
Have you tried to use smaller values for those parameters?

Comment: your imageview is set to wrap_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set width and height to "**wrap_content**" value. It means that images assuming their smallest possible size. Change in your layout resource the  tag with height and width to "**match_parent**" instead.

In the **one_book.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_image"
        android:src="@drawable/book"
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> <!-- THESE width and height -->
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the value "wrap_content" to width and height it will take the minimum required space. in your case you have given

```
 android:minHeight="200dp"
```

to gridView item. So try changing the values of width and height of the ImageView you are using inside **one_book.xml** like :-

```
 android:layout_width="80dp" 
 android:layout_height="100dp"
```

to fit it according to the your gridView item.

Also remember that images will get blurred if you increase ImageView size larger than size of images you are putting inside them so try to resize images after fixing the ImageView size.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use `ConstraintLayout` and `scaleType` for this. The entire **one_book.xml** is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:padding="12sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/book_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/book"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/book_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/author_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/book_image"
        tools:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text_view"
        tools:text="Author" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Demo Image]

Hope this helps. Please Comment if any issues.